# producing a bash command with awk giving runaway string constant - awk

Tags: linux, bash, awk, chef-infra

I'm using `awk` to parse `/etc/hosts` and produce a command which will format `MapR` for me. It's being done in a `bash` utility in `Chef`:

```
egrep '^[0-9]' /etc/hosts | grep -v 127.0.0.1 \
      | awk 'NR==1{ips=$1} 
              NR>1{ips=ips ", " $1} 
              $2=="namenode"{nn=$1} 
              END{ printf "/opt/mapr/server/configure.sh -C %s -Z %s -N mycluster --create-user -D /dev/xvdb\n", ips, nn}' \
      | bash
  sleep 60
```

The command above should execute the following command:

```
/opt/mapr/server/configure.sh -C 10.32.237.251 -Z 10.32.237.251 -N mycluster --create-user -D /dev/xvdb
```

However, looking into my `chef` output I see:

```
==> namenode: Executing awk utility
==> namenode: awk: line 1: runaway string constant "/opt/mapr/ ...
```

The command never got executed in the `MapR` node... However when i execute it directly on the terminal it works nicely in the way it's supposed to be. What am I doing wrong? 
I'm updating the question to show the complete `bash` script that executes that utility:

```
DISK_CONFIG=/home/ubuntu/disk_config
if [ -f $DISK_CONFIG ];
then
  echo "File already exists"
else
  echo "Executing awk utility\n"
  touch $DISK_CONFIG
  egrep '^[0-9]' /etc/hosts | grep -v 127.0.0.1 \
      | awk 'NR==1{ips=$1} 
              NR>1{ips=ips ", " $1} 
              $2=="namenode"{nn=$1} 
              END{ printf "/opt/mapr/server/configure.sh -C %s -Z %s -N mycluster --create-user -D /dev/xvdb\n", ips, nn}' \
      | bash
  sleep 60
fi
```

Comment: What you've written looks impeccable (well, clean enough that it shouldn't generate that error, at any rate).  Therefore, we have to guess that you've somehow executed something different from the script you've shown us.  I suggest dropping the `| bash` and `sleep 60` for the time being and running the rest of the script via `bash -x`.  See what that gives you.  (When I try it on a Mac, it 'works', though there is no 'namenode' value so the command has only spaces between the `-Z` and the `-N`.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I've added the remaining of the script. It's a bash script that gets executed by chef. I also don't think the `| bash` and `sleep 60` are the causes, since they weren't there before.

Comment: Neither the `| bash` nor the `sleep 60` cause your problem, but while testing, you don't want to accidentally execute the `configure.sh` script, nor do you want to wait 60 seconds between attempts to try your script out.  Either 'chef' is screwing you up or it isn't running the code you think it is running. I'm not familiar with 'chef'. Test your script at the command line (without the bash or sleep). Use `bash -x yourscript.sh` to see what is going on. If it is what you show, you should not get the error. Have you accidentally used a word-processing double-quote (`“` or `”`) instead of `"`?

Comment: It's the `-v` on `awk` - you have no variables.

Comment: Since you're on Ubuntu, you might need to check what happens with `dash` instead of `bash`, or with `sh` instead of `bash`.  Try `sh -x yourscript.sh` and `dash -x yourscript.sh` to see whether either of those does anything useful.

Comment: @MarkSetchell: yup; that could do it.  It's also noticeable that the `-v` is missing from the original presentation of the code.  It is so difficult to debug code when the key information is missing!  …But…having said that, with BSD `awk`, I get 'invalid -v option' and with GNU `awk` I get a complete usage message with the `-v` added.

Comment: I can't believe it took me 8 minutes of staring at it!

Comment: @MarkSetchell No, the `-v` option is not the cause ... I'm still trying to figure out that problem

Comment: @JonathanLeffler the `/opt/mapr/server/configure.sh` is from `MapR`. I'm just programmatically configuring it. Here's one example from `MapR`'s website: `/opt/mapr/server/configure.sh -C r1n1.sj.us,r3n1.sj.us,r5n1.sj.us -Z r1n1.sj.us,r2n1.sj.us,r3n1.sj.us,r4n1.sj.us,r5n1.sj.us -HS r5n1.sj.us -N MyCluster`

Comment: That's all fine, but almost all tangential to your `awk` problem.  There is something funny about the `awk` script, and it is far from clear what since the code posted in the question works OK (now that the stray `-v` is gone).  But that `-v` suggests that we still aren't seeing sufficiently accurately what is causing the problem — and it is hard to guess how you've made a mistake when you don't show us the exact code that is giving you the mistake.  When I copy'n'paste your code, all the characters are strictly ASCII (U+0020..U+007D, apart from U+000A newline).

Comment: I would also be interested on the chef recipe, it's easy to get strange behaviors from quoting when not using heredoc syntax.

Comment: The `\n` in the `awk` statement can be causing the problem. Could you try with `\\n` instead?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using HEREDOC syntax in your bash resource:

```
bash "whatever" do
  code <<-EOH
    DISK_CONFIG=/tmp/disk_config
    if [ -f $DISK_CONFIG ];
    then
      echo "File already exists"
    else
      echo "Executing awk utility\n"
      touch $DISK_CONFIG
      egrep '^[0-9]' /etc/hosts | grep -v 127.0.0.1 \
          | awk 'NR==1{ips=$1}
                  NR>1{ips=ips ", " $1}
                  $2=="namenode"{nn=$1}
                  END{ printf "/opt/mapr/server/configure.sh -C %s -Z %s -N mycluster --create-user -D /dev/xvdb\n", ips, nn}' \
          | bash
    fi
  EOH
end
```

this one leads to your error:

```
Executing awk utility

awk: line 4: runaway string constant "/opt/mapr/ ...
```

This is due to the \n in your comand (the one into the awk command is likely to be problematic too)

This resource should do (warning I did replace the DISK_CONFIG path for my tests):

```
bash "whatever" do
  code <<-EOH
    DISK_CONFIG=/tmp/disk_config
    if [ -f $DISK_CONFIG ];
    then
      echo "File already exists"
    else
      echo "Executing awk utility"
      touch $DISK_CONFIG
      egrep '^[0-9]' /etc/hosts | grep -v 127.0.0.1 \
           | awk 'NR==1{ips=$1}
              NR>1{ips=ips ", " $1}
              $2=="namenode"{nn=$1}
              END{ printf "/opt/mapr/server/configure.sh -C %s -Z %s -N mycluster --create-user -D /dev/xvdb", ips, nn}' \
           | bash
      sleep 60
    fi
  EOH
end
```

The reason is that Chef already interpret the `\n` in the code and so awk see a string never ending (runaway).

As you pipe to bash you can omit the `\n` as the pipe will end the line.

Comment: Note to readers: if you're using the `<<-word` heredoc form, ensure there is nothing but **tab** characters preceding `word` to end the doc.

Comment: @glennjackman It's the heredoc reference, but in ruby any number of space works as long as the ending word is alone on it's line. (and without the `-` before the starting word the ending word has to be at start of line, we're complete on the warnings I think ;)).